# rsync from macOS to Linux

Tags: mac-osx, rsync

I did a backup to a remote NFS folder using rsync, from a Mac to a remote Debian system. The final backup is 58GB less than the original. Rsync says that everything was OK, and there's nothing to update.

```
Macintosh:/Volumes/Data1 root# du -sh Produccion/
319G    Produccion/


root@Disketera:/mnt/soho_storage/samba/shares# du -sh Produccion/
260G    Produccion/
```

Can I trust rsync?

I'm using `rsync -av --stats /Volumes/Data1/Produccion/ /mnt/red/`
(/mnt/red is my samba mountpoint)

Some different folders:

```
root@Disketera:/mnt/soho_storage/samba/shares/Produccion/tiposok# du -sh *
0       IndoSanBol
0       IndoSans-Bold
0       IndoSans-Italic
0       IndoSans-Light
0       IndoSans-Regular
40K     PalatinoLTStd-Black.otf
40K     PalatinoLTStd-BlackItalic.otf
40K     PalatinoLTStd-Bold.otf
44K     PalatinoLTStd-BoldItalic.otf
44K     PalatinoLTStd-Italic.otf
40K     PalatinoLTStd-Light.otf
40K     PalatinoLTStd-LightItalic.otf
40K     PalatinoLTStd-Medium.otf
40K     PalatinoLTStd-MediumItalic.otf
56K     PalatinoLTStd-Roman.otf
12K     TCL IndoSans_mac

Macintosh:/Volumes/Data1/Produccion/tiposok root# du -sh *
 36K    IndoSanBol
 40K    IndoSans-Bold
 36K    IndoSans-Italic
 36K    IndoSans-Light
 36K    IndoSans-Regular
 40K    PalatinoLTStd-Black.otf
 40K    PalatinoLTStd-BlackItalic.otf
 40K    PalatinoLTStd-Bold.otf
 44K    PalatinoLTStd-BoldItalic.otf
 44K    PalatinoLTStd-Italic.otf
 40K    PalatinoLTStd-Light.otf
 40K    PalatinoLTStd-LightItalic.otf
 40K    PalatinoLTStd-Medium.otf
 40K    PalatinoLTStd-MediumItalic.otf
 56K    PalatinoLTStd-Roman.otf
160K    TCL IndoSans_mac
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the backup is not complete. With some fonts, like InSanBol, the resource fork is missing which is used in older Mac fonts to store the glyph data.

I am not sure at the moment, but maybe using `--xattrs` as a parameter will help. I also would recommend to include ACL's so you end up with

```
 rsync -aAXv --stats /Volumes/Data1/Produccion/ /mnt/red/
```

I forgot: MacOS ships with a stone-old version of rsync which is broken beyond repair anyway. I would install MacPorts and after that, install a fresh rsync version with the command

```
sudo port install rsync
```

(This is quite involved, as it requires the Apple Developer Tools to compile rsync).

Comment: Macintosh:/ root# rsync -aAXv --stats /Volumes/Data1/Produccion/ /mnt/red/
rsync: -aAXv: unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-35.2/rsync/main.c(1333) [client=2.6.9]

Comment: I'm reading a bit and this is a known issue about HFS and its metadata, but I don't need it. I just need the files.

Comment: See my edit to hints on that.

Comment: Yeah, but the font files will be broken, as they are stored as metadata.

Comment: "MacOS ships with a stone-old version of rsync which is broken beyond repair anyway" - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Under 10.6.6 according to the rsync man page, the option is -E, not -X, also, -A doesn't exist, so the command options would be -aEv.

Comment: This option works between Macs only.